# Node.js for non-web servers?

Tags: node.js

Node.js can be used for servers which are not web related. For example, this [IRC server](https://github.com/alexyoung/ircd.js).

What kind of performance can I expect from Node.js in a non-web server role?

Is Node.js a good choice to build a general-purpose (non-web) server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a good way to build a server of
>   something non-web related?

Yes. Its strength is in DIRT applications (data intensive, real time).

> I would like to know the real
>   perfomance of Node.js

What does this mean? In what context? This is too vague a way to approach performance of any type. You need specific goals in mind for a project, and then you can judge what tool is right for the job.

Comment: You just answered to my question, thank you very much, that was all I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes some people already used it for non-web application:

http://www.heatsynclabs.org/boutduinode-a-pool-party-with-arduino-node-js-and-an-rc-boat/

https://github.com/brianlovesdata/node-serialport

Hope this help

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing those projects! I know it's possible to build some non-web projects, however, I would like to know the real perfomance of Node.js...